# Using compiled java code in a native application

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a native C++ application that uses Java library, in a bunch of jar files, via JNI. There's now an issue as to how to distribute the application to a third party without compromising security.

We're worried that jar files can be reverse engineered easily. After digging around, I found one solutions for this problem is to use an AOT Java compiler suggested [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29866/reverse-engineering-and-java).

If I use the AOT Java compiler and make a native lib file, will I still be able to use JNI to call the Java methods the same way I'm doing now with jar files.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I hope you do realize that AOT compilation doesn't solve any security problem, because native code can still be reverse engineered albeit with added difficulty. Also, you mention *encrypted* jar files in the title, but the the question doesn't seem to mention encryption at all.

Comment: @user2079303 Sorry I was considering encrypted jar files when I started this question. But found an [issue](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077342/core-java/cracking-java-byte-code-encryption.html) with that method and changed my question. Also, we're already distributing our binaries, it is more of a business requirement right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no perfect solution.  If there was your code would not be able to run.

The best you can do is to estimate the benefit of having the source code in dollars, and to obfuscate the code sufficiently to be more expensive to reverse than the benefit.

And by the way, in mixed code shops I often see people hold Java to unreasonable standards, while their non-Java code is not even protected.  What do you do to prevent C++ reversing?

Comment: The relative ease with which a class file can be deciphered was the reason to look into protecting the jars. That said, it looks like code obfuscation is the way to go for us.

Comment: @ArunR It is relatively easy for me to reverse C++.  It's just that there is no culture of fear around C++ reversing; because, most of the C++ code isn't really worth reversing.  However, back in the day when various half-baked protection schemes were flourishing, one could gain a lot of BBS street cred by finding the (effective) `if (!authorized) then` statement and forcing the conditional to always be true.  Oh, and my previous statement isn't a C++ language attack, most Java code isn't worth reversing too!